# What is this shown in the picture? (An interface in iPad)

Tags: xcode, xcode4, ipad

As shown in the picture 1, there is an extra button (red circle) in the tabbar controller. How is it accomplished?

What's more, when the red circled button is clicked, the yellow zone in picture 2 scrolls up (actually the whole screen). Does this interface have a name? Is there nay existing view controller could do something similar?

=== Update ===

Knowing that this is a custom UI, could anyone give me some hints on how to implement it?

Picture 1:

[image]

Picture 2:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a custom-designed UI pattern that isn't available out of the box. I imagine it's pretty simple to implement. All you'd need is a UITabBarController and a way to wire up the tab button event to the parent view. Once the button is clicked, move the UITabBarController view up to expose the underlying photo view.

Comment: Thanks for your fast response. After knowing this, may I ask for more hints on making it?

Comment: I'm tempted to scratch out some code, but.. not right now. :) Hopefully my update gives you some guidance as to how to get started.